# Should I symbolize keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

1) I am grabbing some records for the DB in HAML to display, and the attributes method on each row returns a hash. The hash's keys are strings. Should I turn those keys into symbols? I am not sure the call to `symbolize_keys` is worth it. I.e.,

```
%td #{app['comment']}
```

or

```
%td #{app[:comment]
```

2) I am trying to symbolize the array of hashes I return, but it is not working:

```
rows = Comment.all(:order => 'created DESC')
result = rows.each_with_object([]) do |row, comments|
   comments << row.attributes.symbolize_keys
end
```

Is it not actually pushing the symbolized hash into the comments array? I also tried `symbolize_keys!`, and that did not help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Rails, you have access to [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) so you can bypass your "strings or symbols" issue quite easily by allow both:

```
h = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(some_model.attributes)
puts h['id'] # Gives you some_model.id
puts h[:id]  # Also gives you some_model.id
```

Your `each_with_object` approach:

```
result = rows.each_with_object([]) do |row, comments|
  comments << row.attributes.symbolize_keys
end
```

should work fine so I think your problem with that lies elsewhere.

Comment: I print out the result array the I am storing this all in and it is not symbolized.

Comment: I get an array of hashes with symbol keys in `result` when I do that `each_with_object`, I have no idea why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a reason for using `ActiveRecord::Base#attributes[your_attribute]` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base#your_attribute` directly? You didn't mention a reason.

`ActiveRecord::Base` automatically sets up accessors for your database fields:

```
object = Model.new
object.your_column = "foo"  # Writer
object.your_column          # Reader
```

You should be able to use the reader in your views instead of accessing the value through `ActiveRecord::Base#attributes`.

**Update:**

I'm not sure if this is what confuses you.

`Comment.find(:all)` already retrieves *all* columns values for those rows in your database and stores them in your Comment objects (which we assign to `@comments` below). The values are already stored in your Comment objects, so you may already use them in your views as you please.

In your controller, if you have:

```
def index
  @comments = Commend.find(:all)  # Fetch columns and rows.
end
```

you can do this in your HAML view:

```
- @comments.each do |comment|     # Iterate through array of Comment objects
  %tr
    %td= comment.comment          # Use value for "comment" column.
```

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your answer :( I am just calling the find(:all) essentially.  I am not sure how to control what I get back as a record.  But I would like to pass back to a client (HAML) an array of all the records.

Answer (score 0):

you can add hook, which symbolizes keys after model load:

```rb
class YourModel < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize do |rec|
    attributes["some_json_field"].symbolize_keys! if attributes.key? "some_json_field"
  end
end
```

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.